# Windows DNS Client service will not start

Tags: networking, dns, windows-services

I previously had a lot of domains blocked using my HOSTS file, but after a reboot it took several minutes for DNS to begin resolving to anything. So I disabled DNS caching as I saw recommended online.

This all became too much of a hassle and I have reverted my HOSTS file back to be much simpler.  Now every web/DNS request seems to take much longer than it should, nothing is being cached. Running the command `net start dnscache` or `net stop dnscache` results in

```
The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later.
```

Investigating further, the DNS Client service in Windows has a "Starting" status and is not changing.

[image: Windows Services]

System Configuration (`MSConfig`) shows "Start Pending"

[image: MSConfig]

What do I need to do to get this back to a working state again?  Web browsing works but it is slower than usual. Other devices on my same network behave normally so I know it's an issue with this machine (windows 11 Home)

---

EDIT to show the dependencies for the DNS Client service
[image: DNS Client Service Dependencies]

Comment: Do you have any event in the event log relating to starting and stopping DNS, that would be the first place to look. Also right click the service, properties, dependencies. Are the services it depends on in the running state?

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: @GeneMoody-Action1 See my update to show the dependencies and yes I have rebooted, nothing has changed

Comment: Are all of those services running, and again what are events surrounding this, maybe clear the system and application logs, reboot to this state, and check them?

Comment: Yes, those 4 dependent services are running. The event log for `Microsoft > Windows > DNS Client Events` shows 0 events. I have now cleared out the application & system events and rebooted again (is that what you meant by "reboot to this state"?) - no changes

Comment: So it is not logging anything at all in system either on a reboot with clean logs?

Comment: DNS Client Events still shows 0 events, and the services still show it as attempting to start. Should I be looking elsewhere for events? Looking through the system events there is an error event: "The DNS Client service hung on starting." and another "The Remote Access Connection Manager service depends on the DNS Client service which failed to start because of the following error: 
After starting, the service hung in a start-pending state."

Answer (score 1):

So this is not a 100% solution as my service is still stuck in the "starting" mode, but I have managed to speed up my DNS resolution so using the internet feels normal again.  However I'm not clear on why this all works at all if the DNS Client has not been started... Whatever I guess, this at least *mostly* works for me for now.

---

I browse with **Firefox**, it can do it's own DNS resolution. I had previously disabled this but I changed the **"Enable secure DNS using:"** setting back to **"Default Protection"**

In **Powershell as Admin** I ran `Clear-DnsClientCache`

In the **registry**:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache
```

There is a `Start` key which should be set to `2` to mean "automatic startup" - it was already set to that. All good there ([source](https://wintechlab.com/enable-disable-dns-client-service/))

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters
```

- Add `DWORD` named `MaxCacheTtl` with value `86400`
- Add `DWORD` named `MaxNegativeCacheTtl` with value `5`

Finally, **restart**.

Things are not perfect but it works for now and browsing is at a normal feeling speed again. An issue I am still noticing is my Spotify client will not connect or is extremely slow. I can use Spotify web client, but not the desktop app. Not sure why.

Also there seemed to have been a service issue with my ISP while I was trying to diagnose this, so that sure didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point anyone to [the answer on a similar question I asked](https://superuser.com/a/1813527/77965) - Basically the "real" solution here is to reinstall Windows.  It's extreme but it worked!