# How to start of reinstall Windows DNS Client?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-services

My Windows 11 machine is unable to start the DNS Client service.  This means that all internet requests are extremely slow since no DNS calls are cached.

Here you can see the service stuck in a perpetual `Starting` status, shown in the Services and in `MSConfig`. Various commands show the same thing or just return no data.
[image: d]

Looking through the system events I saw these error events:

```
The DNS Client service hung on starting.
```

```
The Remote Access Connection Manager service depends on the DNS Client service which
failed to start because of the following error: After starting, the service hung
in a start-pending state.
```

I have tried creating a new user account in hope that it was something specific to my account, but the new account does the same thing. At this point all I know to do is to re-install Windows, but that feels too drastic and I'd really like to avoid that option.

What do I need to do to fix this so the DNS client/cache runs again?

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC ......  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
  ...  See if this restores your DNS client.

Comment: seems something wrong with DNS settings in your IP configuration ?

Comment: @John Thanks for the tip. #1 completed, but #2 hung up at 62.3% for about an hour. I've restarted it and it's not really doing anything... not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS client is built right into Windows (any version).

The usual thing to start with to repair is DISM / SFC.

**(1)** Since that did not work, then I suggest now a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.

Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.

Proceed normally answering the prompts.

The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Start with Keep Everything and see if that works. Normally 75% of the time or greater it will work.

**(2)** If Repair Install does not work (in this case both DISM and Repair hang up), then what you need to do next is back up and reinstall Windows 11 fresh. Then restore Apps and data from the backup.

Comment: I've run the tool and it's been installed on a USB hard drive. When I run `setup.exe` it gets to the "downloading updates" stage and just sits there. Perf monitor shows no network traffic, so it's not downloading anything. Do I have to boot from this drive to get it to do something?

Comment: If both DISM and Setup from the Windows ISO fail, then you need to reinstall Windows 11.  I did add this to my answer.

Comment: After a restart the USB drive ended up working and my DNS service now runs. Thanks you!